# Ajax passing value to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to pass multiple values to php via ajax (on same page), here's my code:

**HTML (user_list.php)**:

```
<button type="submit" class="button button-block savebutton" name="save_changes"/>
        Save changes</button>
```

**Javascript (user_list.php)**:

```
$(".savebutton").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var js = [];
    var i = 0;
    $('select').each(function () {
        var a = {"id": "", "permission": ""}
        a.id = $(this).val();
        a.permission = $(this).children(":selected").text();
        js.push(a);
        alert(js[i].permission + " - "+js[i].id);
        i++;
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user_list.php",
        data: {result: JSON.stringify(js)}
    });
    return false;
});
```

**PHP (user_list.php)**:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

if (isset($_POST['delete_selected'])) { // Button to delete selected user(s)

    if (!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $id) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$id";
            $mysqli->query($sql);
            header("Refresh:0"); //Refresh page
        }
    }

}

// Other if above works fine
elseif (isset($_POST['result'])){
    // I want to get the js array with the values here after ajax
}

else {
    // But I get here, and I don't get the js array
}
}
```

So I have 2 problems, the first is that I pass the elseif, and the second is that I dont get the array. I think the problem is with ajax, since filling the array works properly

**EDIT**: I moved the php to a different page, now it's working.

Comment: Check your Ajax request with browser dev tools. Does the request look good there?

Comment: What are the other conditions in the `if` statement? It's possible one of those is hitting and short-circuiting the else if's

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` at the beginning of you PHP script. What does that show?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó
array(2) { ["permission_select"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(2) "15" [2]=> string(2) "16" [3]=> string(2) "17" } ["save_changes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }

Comment: Don't stringify the array if you want to read it immediately as array in php

Comment: Also do what @Zoli is telling you. Have to prevent default form submit

Comment: Hey..can you remove the stringify and check..

Comment: Just pass as array..don't stringify..let's see if there's any change..

Comment: @Darshan nothing has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your Ajax request is initiated, a "normal" submit request is also started, when you press the button. To prevent the second request (thus keeping only the Ajax request), you have to `return false;` at the end of your `onclick` callback.

Solution #1:

```
$(".savebutton").on("click", function () {
    var js = [];
    var i = 0;
    $('select').each(function () {
        var a = {"id": "", "permission": ""}
        a.id = $(this).val();
        a.permission = $(this).children(":selected").text();
        js.push(a);
        alert(js[i].permission + " - "+js[i].id);
        i++;
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user_list.php",
        data: {result: JSON.stringify(js)}
    });
    return false;
});
```

Solution #2 (as also suggested by @charlietfl):

```
$(".savebutton").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var js = [];
    var i = 0;
    $('select').each(function () {
        var a = {"id": "", "permission": ""}
        a.id = $(this).val();
        a.permission = $(this).children(":selected").text();
        js.push(a);
        alert(js[i].permission + " - "+js[i].id);
        i++;
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user_list.php",
        data: {result: JSON.stringify(js)}
    });
});
```

Comment: Or use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: That did help, now I see the post methods in network monitor.

Comment: But I still dont get to the php part.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your full php code, so we can help you with the php part too.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó done, but the first if works fine, I only have problems with the second one

Comment: So let us get this right: Ajax request gets executed now without being interrupted by the second "normal" submit request (i.e. your page does not refresh when pressing the submit button). But you still land in the final `else`?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó Exactly, I submit the button, page doesn't refresh, and I land in the final else (and I need the second if).

Comment: What's the output of the `var_dump` when you check your Ajax request's response in the network monitor? Also, how does your request parameters look like in the network monitor? (Eventually post screenshots)

Comment: Request parameters look OK. What about the "Response" tab?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.savebutton').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var js = []
  var i = 0
  $('select').each(function (i) {
    var a = {}
    a.id = $(this).val()
    a.permission = $(this).children(':selected').text()
    js.push(a)
    alert(js[i].permission + ' - ' + js[i].id)
  })
  js = JSON.stringify(js)
  $.post('user_list.php', {result: js}
})
```

Comment: Where's the explanation? Code only answers are not good quality if they don't explain why the code would make a difference or what was changed and why

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you're submitting the POST request, the data is coming as their own POST fields. Simply check for the values of what you submitted. For example, if you had done the same, but put `foo` as `bar` and `hello` as `world`, you could check for `foo` and `hello` with something like this:

```
elseif (isset($_POST['foo'], $_POST['hello']) {
    # your code
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with this

```
<button type="submit" class="button button-block savebutton" name="save_changes[]"/>Save changes</button>
```

Comment: that didn't help :(